# Linq return intersection of one property in a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a an IEnumerable of a set of objects that contains a set of Scores.
I need to create one last object at the end of the IEnumerable that will define the Total Score.

This object contains the same columns and each will be an intersection of the properties of the objects in the list.
Ex: the property in the totalscore will represent the intersection of all the others, if at least one Fail then it should present Fail. Pass is only if all objects in the list have Pass score

This is the score definition:

```
public enum Score
{
    NotRated = 0x00,
    Pass = 0x01,
    Fail = 0x03
}
```

I already converted the IEnumerable to a List and added a new item like this:

```
projectedResult.Add(
            new
            {
                Title = "Total Result",

                IOTest = from rst in projectedResult
                         rst.IOTest ... #### *1 ####,
            }
        );
```

*1 - this is where I need the intersection of the same property across all objects in projectedResult

Comment: "return Pass if all Pass or Fail if all Fail and the same for Not Rated" What's the result supposed to be if the property values are heterogeneous?

Comment: All the objects in the list contains the same properties, the last one "Total Score" will just present the intersection of them all.. Something lilke Pass & Pass & Fail = Fail

Comment: enum can be cast to an integer : (int)NotRated == 0x01

Answer (score 2):

Given your definition of values, and the lack of desired results if the values aren't the same,

```
IOTest = (Score)projectedResult.Aggregate(0x00, (ttlrst, rst) => ttlrst | rst.IOTest )
```

Comment: Done, similar, but works projectedResult.Aggregate(Score.NotRated, (ttlrst, rst) => ttlrst | rst.IOTest); thanks